# Java Navigate with tabulator key through custom JCheckBoxList

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlist, jcheckbox

I have build myself a custom `JList` with `JCheckBox`'s as items. It all works pretty good but now I want to be able to select a `CheckBox` with keyboard inputs only. Also I don't want to use Mnemonics for each `CheckBox` item.

Is there a way to implement some kind of `FocusListener` or something so that I can navigate with tabulator key?

I tried setting the `setFocusPainted(true)` etc. but nothing worked for me.

Thanks for your time and help.

My code:

```
public class JCheckBoxList extends JList<Object>{

private DefaultListModel<Object> model = null;
private JCheckBoxList selfPointer = null;
private boolean enabled = true;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public JCheckBoxList() {
    super();
    model = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    selfPointer = this;
    this.setModel(model);
    this.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxListCellRenderer());
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            int clicked_index = selfPointer.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
            if (evt.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
                //right clicked
            }else {
                //left clicked
                if (enabled) {
                    setSelected(clicked_index, !isSelected(clicked_index));
                    selfPointer.repaint(selfPointer.getCellBounds(clicked_index, clicked_index));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    this.setVisibleRowCount(50);
    this.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
}

/**
 * Add new CheckBoxListItem to the JCheckBoxList.
 * @param name Name of new Item.
 */
public void addElement(String name) {
    model.addElement(new CheckBoxListItem(name));
}

/**
 * Add new CheckBoxListItem to the JCheckBoxList.
 * @param name Name of new Item.
 * @param isSelected Boolean if new Item should be selected or not after creating.
 */
public void addElement(String name, boolean isSelected) {
    CheckBoxListItem item = new CheckBoxListItem(name);
    item.setSelected(isSelected);
    model.addElement(item);
}

/**
 * Get all selected Values from JCheckBoxList.
 * @return ArrayList of type String with all selected values.
 */
public List<String> getSelectedValueList() {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
        if (((CheckBoxListItem)model.getElementAt(i)).isSelected == true) {
            returnList.add(model.getElementAt(i).toString());
        }
    }
    if (returnList.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    return returnList;
}

/**
 * Replaces Element at an specific index. Removes the old and creates a new one.
 * @param index Integer index to identify object to replace.
 * @param name Name of new item.
 */
public void replaceElementAt(int index, String name) {
    model.removeElementAt(index);
    model.insertElementAt(new CheckBoxListItem(name), index);;
}

/**
 * Removes all Elements from JCheckBoxList.
 */
public void removeAll() {
    model.removeAllElements();
}

/**
 * Custom getElementAt method. Same functionality as List method.
 * @param index Integer index of Element to get.
 * @return Return String name of Element.
 */
public String getElementAt(int index) {
    return model.getElementAt(index).toString();
}

/**
 * Check if an Element is Selected.
 * @param index Integer Index to identify Element.
 * @return Returns whether Element is selected or not.
 */
public boolean isSelected(int index) {
     return ((CheckBoxListItem)model.getElementAt(index)).isSelected;
}

/**
 * Set the selected state of Element.
 * @param index Integer Index of identify Element.
 * @param isSelected Boolean value to set.
 */
public void setSelected(int index, boolean isSelected) {
    ((CheckBoxListItem)model.getElementAt(index)).setSelected(isSelected);
}   

@Override
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.swing.JComponent#setEnabled(boolean)
 */
public void setEnabled(boolean arg0) {
    enabled = arg0;
}

@Override
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.awt.Component#isEnabled()
 */
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

/**
 * Get all Values from JCheckBoxList as ArrayList.
 * @return Returns ArrayList of type String with content of JCheckBoxList.
 */
public List<String> getValues() {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
        returnList.add(model.getElementAt(i).toString());
    }
    return returnList;
}

private class CheckBoxListItem {
    private String label;
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    private CheckBoxListItem(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    private boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    private void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private class CheckBoxListCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        setComponentOrientation(list.getComponentOrientation());
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
        setSelected(((CheckBoxListItem) value).isSelected());
        setEnabled(enabled);
        setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());  

        return this;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> I have build myself a custom JList with JCheckBox's as items.

Use a single column JTable.

A JTable already supports checkboxes and you can change the state of the checkbox using the keyboard or the mouse. It also supports tabbing from cell to cell.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a basic example to get you started.

If you don't want the header of the table you can just set the table header to null.

Otherwise just use a JPanel with the checkboxes. A JList is only designed to display data, not react to event or change state of the objects being rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your response but could you give an example? I cant really find a good implementation only with just a single column.

Answer (score 0):

use the method

```
setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(boolean);
```

on your component to (dis)allow traversal keys (like TAB) as key inputs